# In Android 4.1 I get E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 130885356-byte allocation. without using bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I know this error exist a lot in Stack overflow , but all the solution about using bitmap and I don't use bitmap in my project

This error happens when I use emulator **Android 4.1**

My project consist of (at first ) **authentication** **Activities** . Every Activity has a background image with `(1324*2746) JPG 75kB` . My app crashes after the third Activity . When I reach to the fourth Activity in gives me the below error .
I tried to use `android:largeHeap="true"` in the `Manifest` but it doesn't work

Here is the error

```
    E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 130885356-byte allocation.
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x9e6a4450 self=0xb87b64e0
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=3341 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1216621504
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=271 stm=186 core=2
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.appsI/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3336)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.<init>(NestedScrollView.java:199)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.<init>(NestedScrollView.java:194)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at com.dms.apps..UI.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:59)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            03-15 17:09:37.721 3341-3341/com.dms.apps. I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try to go directly to 4th Activity and check if the problem is 4th background

Comment: I tired that and it worked without errors . So what is the problem ?

Comment: 1324x2746 is not 75kb for Memory but 1324x2746x3=11MB because it should be decoded in a Bitmap (uncompressed pixels). So 11*4 = 44MB for 4 background images. It's very strange that the Emulated Device cannot manage 44MB of Bitmap, but it could be (Android 4.1 is very very old and I cannot be sure). Try to "finish()" previous Activities before open the next.

Comment: But I need to go back to the previous activity

Comment: If the problem is Memory limit it means that you cannot hold 4 background in the same time. You could just free the Background of previous Activity and recreate it when the user goes back to it, in this way 98% of the Activity remains intact and only the Background need to be reload. This solution makes the App lighter because only 1 background is held in memory at the same time.

Comment: So what should I do ? resize the image ? what is your advice ?